# Recipient detail in SendGrid Dynamic Template

Tags: sendgrid

I need to send a payload to multiple recipients in SendGrid. I use the Dynamic Templates to construct the email body, and all is working fine.

I would like to add a 'Hi `{{recipientName}}`' line to the email but I cannot find any documentation on it, is it possible?

I cannot include the recipient detail in the payload as a single payload goes out to many recipients

Comment: What programming language

Comment: Also, why not use a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [personalizations](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/personalizations).

> Personalizations allow you to override these various metadata for each email in an API request.

Your request will look like this:

```
{
  "from": "gilbert@techmail.com",
  "template_id": "YOUR TEMPLATE ID",
  "personalizations": [
    {
      "to": [
        {
          "email": "john@example.com"
        }
      ],
      "substitutions": {
        "%fname%": "John",
        "%CustomerID%": "C001"
      },

    },
    {
      "to": [
        {
          "email": "peter@example.com"
        }
      ],
      "substitutions": {
        "%fname%": "Peter",
        "%CustomerID%": "C005"
      },
      "send_at": 1629723541
    }
  ]
}
```

and it will go as a single request.

Also look at [this](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/issues/269#issuecomment-898764656) github comment.

Comment: gh link broken.